# Rails render wrong format type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a problem with rails `respond_with`, sometimes it renders json instead of html when I access it through browser. The problem sometimes occurs sometimes not, usually when the load time is high.

Here's the specification

1. In the controller, I use `respond_to :html, :json`
2. In the last statement of action, I use `respond_with(@object)`
3. I use same endpoint (i.e /reports, not /reports nor /reports.json) for both browser (html) and mobile (json), the json request is done by attaching http header with `accept: application/json`. It works well on json request, only html request that sometimes render the json instead of html
4. ruby v2.3.1 and rails v4.2.6
5. Only happens on production with nginx server, never happens on development
6. production server: unicorn v5.1.0
7. I use my own responder to get json key instead of formatted error message when the record isn't valid, in ApplicationController I put `self.responder = ApiResponder`

This is the code of ApiResponder:

```
class ApiResponder < ActionController::Responder
  def json_resource_errors
    I18n.locale = "json"
    resource.valid? # this refreshes locale in which error messages are translated
    { errors: resource.errors }
  end

  protected

    def api_behavior
      raise MissingRenderer.new(format) unless has_renderer?

      if get?
        display resource
      elsif post?
        display resource, :status => :created, :location => api_location
      elsif patch? or put?
        display resource, :status => :ok, :location => api_location
      else
        head :no_content
      end
    end
end
```

This is the log from rails request when it wrong render json instead of html:

```
I, [2017-07-25T02:50:02.594851 #23977]  INFO -- : Started GET "/reports" for x.x.x.x at 2017-07-25 02:50:02 +0000
I, [2017-07-25T02:50:02.596151 #23977]  INFO -- : Processing by ReportsController#index as HTML
I, [2017-07-25T02:50:03.237783 #23977]  INFO -- :   Rendered regions/_region.json.jbuilder (0.4ms)
I, [2017-07-25T02:50:03.238063 #23977]  INFO -- :   Rendered sales/_sales.json.jbuilder (1.0ms)
...truncated...
I, [2017-07-25T02:50:03.284629 #23977]  INFO -- :   Rendered reports/index.json.jbuilder (61.7ms)
I, [2017-07-25T02:50:03.285204 #23977]  INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 689ms (Views: 56.0ms | ActiveRecord: 68.7ms)
```

As you see, rails see the request as HTML but I have no idea why it renders json.

And here's the log when it renders html normally:

```
I, [2017-07-25T02:52:05.132039 #8991]  INFO -- : Started GET "/reports" for x.x.x.x at 2017-07-25 02:52:05 +0000
I, [2017-07-25T02:52:05.187351 #8991]  INFO -- : Processing by ReportsController#index as HTML
I, [2017-07-25T02:52:06.115379 #8991]  INFO -- :   Rendered shared/_filter_date.html.erb (1.0ms)
I, [2017-07-25T02:52:06.161682 #8991]  INFO -- :   Rendered reports/_reports.html.erb (45.6ms)
I, [2017-07-25T02:52:06.163072 #8991]  INFO -- :   Rendered reports/index.html.erb within layouts/application (51.2ms)
I, [2017-07-25T02:52:06.181696 #8991]  INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 994ms (Views: 66.3ms | ActiveRecord: 84.9ms)
```

Both request above are accessed from browser, but the former renders json (should be html).

I wonder if this related with server or production configuration and production, because it never happens on development.

Comment: can you upload your report controller (index part)

Comment: @widjajayd Nothing wrong with the index part, even if I just put `@reports =  Report.all; respond_with(@reports)` it still _sometimes_ render wrong format